# Landau Theory of a Crystal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, stability

A crystal has ferroelectric and ferromagnetic properties. Suppose that the ferromagnetic transition
occurs at a temperature $T_m$ slightly higher than the ferroelectric transition $T_{e}$, and that reasons of symmetry dictate that the Landau expansion at magnetization $M$ and polarization $P$ has, at the lowest order, the form:

$$F(M,T,P) = F_{0}(T) + \frac{1}{2}a_{1}\left(T - \Theta_{1} \right)M^{2} + \frac{1}{2}a_{2}\left(T - \Theta_{2} \right)P^{2} + \frac{1}{4}b_{1}M^{4} + \frac{1}{4}b_{2}P^{4} + \frac{1}{2}c M^{2}P^{2} \, .$$

For a phase purely ferromagnetic $(T_{m} > T > T_{e})$ and we only consider terms associated with magnetization, thus we can write:

$$F(M,T) = F_{0}(T) + \frac{1}{2}a_{1}\left(T - \Theta_{1} \right)M^{2} + \frac{1}{4}b_{1}M^{4}+ \frac{1}{2}c M^{2}P^{2} \, .$$
In order to study the stability of it, I wrote:

$$\frac{dF}{dM} = 0 \rightarrow a_{1}\left(T - \Theta_{1} \right)M + b_{1}M^{3}+ c MP^{2} = 0 \, ,$$

$$\delta F = 0 \rightarrow 2a_{1}\left(T - \Theta_{1} \right)M^{2} + b_{1}M^{4} + 2c M^{2}P^{2} = 0 \, .$$

I'm supposed to find that:

$$\frac{a_{1}c}{a_{2}b_{1}} < 1 \, ,$$

$$\theta_{2} = T_{e} + \frac{a_{1}c}{a_{2}b_{1}} \left(T_{m} - T_{e} \right) \, .$$

However, in expression (1) and (2) I do not have any term like that ones above. Am I doing something wrong?